# "how do I filter everything out of my dictionary except the items with the smallest nonzero values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

my current code:

```
string = str(input("please input a string:  "))
vowel_count = {c:string.count(c) for c in 'aeoiu'}
print(vowel_count)
```

Sorry i did have a post before but it was mixed up with two questions.

Before i was trying different things with for loops to try and find the lowest number in the dictionary above 0 and then print them. even if there was more than one with the same value.

if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

thanks
charlie

Comment: What is expected output if the input is `smallest nonzero values`? `{'a': 2, 'e': 3, 'u': 1, 'o': 2}` / `{'u': 1}` / `u` / `1` ?

Comment: You mean like adding ` if string.count(c)` in your dict comprehension?

Comment: expected output would be: u = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the smallest non-zero value:

```
>>> string = 'smallest nonzero values'
>>> vowel_count = {c:string.count(c) for c in 'aeoiu'}
>>> m = min(cnt for ch, cnt in vowel_count.items() if cnt > 0)
```

Filter alphabets by the number:

```
>>> {ch: cnt for ch, cnt in vowel_count.items() if cnt == m}
{'u': 1}

>>> ['{}={}'.format(ch, cnt) for ch, cnt in vowel_count.items() if cnt == m]
['u=1']
>>> ', '.join('{}={}'.format(ch, cnt) for ch, cnt in vowel_count.items() if cnt == m)
'u=1'
```

NOTE: If there's no vowel, `min(...)` will raise `ValueError`. You need to catch the exception.

```
>>> vowel_count = {'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'u': 0}
>>> min(cnt for ch, cnt in vowel_count.items() if cnt > 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

I don't know what you want for such case. I'll leave it for you.